# Elasticsearch: How to optimize the source parameter in a script function?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following data in an Elasticsearch index called `products`

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 1,
          "currency" : "USD",
          "price" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 2,
          "currency" : "INR",
          "price" : 60
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 3,
          "currency" : "EUR",
          "price" : 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "prod_id" : 5,
          "currency" : "MYR",
          "price" : 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am sorting the data based on the `price` field,
I have the following script to do so -

```
GET products/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "functions": [{
                "script_score": {
                    "script": {
                        "params": {
                            "USD": 1,
                            "SGD": 0.72,
                            "MYR": 0.24,
                            "INR": 0.014,
                            "EUR": 1.12
                        },
                        "source": "doc['price'].value * (doc.currency.value == 'eur'? params.EUR : doc.currency.value == 'myr' ? params.MYR : doc.currency.value == 'inr' ? params.INR : 1)"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Because the field `currency` in the `product` index is of type text,
it is indexed with **Standard Analyzer**, which converts it to lower case.

**I wish to optimise this part of the script, As I may end up with 20-30 currencies -**

```
"source": "doc['price'].value * (doc.currency.value == 'eur'? params.EUR : doc.currency.value == 'myr' ? params.MYR : doc.currency.value == 'inr' ? params.INR : 1)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I was able to optimize the source script with the following working solution -**

```
GET products/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "functions": [{
                "script_score": {
                    "script": {
                        "params": {
                            "USD": 1,
                            "SGD": 0.72,
                            "MYR": 0.24,
                            "INR": 0.014,
                            "EUR": 1.12
                        },
                        "source": "doc['price'].value * params[doc['currency.keyword'].value]"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```